# AngularJS multiselect custom filter not working as intended

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, multi-select, angularjs-filter

In an AngularJS record display (with filters) I have a multiselect array of territories that a user can select from to find out if a certain item is available in a certain territory.

The array returns a list of values such as

```
['001','010','200']
```

based on the ID of the territories selected. This is then checked against a  JSON list of records which has a JSON value looks like this

```
territoriesnotavailable: "001, 085, 090"
```

Each record either has this set to null, or has a list from one to many numbers.

I currently use the following code (customFilter) which works perfectly if you only select ONE value.. it basically makes the item filter out if the territory selected in the multiselect is in the list of territoriesnotavailable

```
function CustomTerritoryFilter() {
    return function(data, query) {
        if (query.length === 0) return data;
        if (data) return data.filter(function(item) {
            for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
                var queryitem = query[i]["id"];

                if(item.territoriesnotavailable) {
                    stringB = item.territoriesnotavailable;
                } else {
                    stringB = 'xxxxxxxx';
                }

                stringA = queryitem;
                if (!(stringB.indexOf( stringA ) > -1)) {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });
        return [];
    };
}
```

So if I choose only one filter (resulting in a query of ['010'] for example. and this appears in territoriesnoavailable for the record.. it vanishes as expected.. but if I choose any value that is NOT in territoriesnotavailable the item appears again.. i need the record to vanish if ANY selected territory appears in the list regardless of any that do not

Comment: I suspect I need to put a failure flag in at some point that stops any more checking

Answer (score 0):

```
function CustomTerritoryFilter() {
    return function(data, query) {
        if (query.length === 0) return data;
        if (data) return data.filter(function(item) {
            for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
                var queryitem = query[i]["id"];
                if(item.territoriesnotavailable) {
                    stringB = item.territoriesnotavailable;
                } else {
                    stringB = 'xxxxxxxx';
                }

                stringA = queryitem;
                if (!(stringB.indexOf( stringA ) > -1)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
        return [];
    };
}
```

Comment: This didnt work for a couple of reasons.. if I chose a value that was IN territoriesnotavailable (tna) the item appeared.. if I chose one that was not in tna it disappeared.. if i had one of each.. it appeared. I finally got a working solution that used a flagging system which works

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I settled on. It basically sets a flag as 1 (show) and then checks each number in the filter.. if there is just one occurance of the number in the list, the flag is set to zero. At the end of the check data is shown if the flaG REMAins as 1

```
function CustomTerritoryFilter() {
    return function(data, query) {
        if (query.length === 0) return data;
        if (data) return data.filter(function(item) {
            var flag = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
                var queryitem = query[i]["id"];

                if(item.territoriesnotavailable) {
                    stringB = item.territoriesnotavailable;
                } else {
                    stringB = 'xxxxxxxx';
                }

                stringA = queryitem;
                if (stringB.indexOf( stringA ) > -1) {
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
            if(flag === 1) {
                return data;
            }
        });
        return [];
    };
}
```